# How do I get all the innerHTML values of a page that needs to scroll?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get prices, account names, and dates from trades on Opensea. My code loads the page, scrolls until it hits the bottom, and then tries to collect the innerHTML of a div. The issue is it only collects 19 random points and not the hundreds or thousands that exist.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://opensea.io/activity?search[collections][0]=fvckrender&search[collections][1]=artifex-fvckrender&search[collections][2]=fvck-limited&search[collections][3]=unidentified-contract-kg9mf80eue&search[eventTypes][0]=AUCTION_SUCCESSFUL")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Code for scrolling down the page
pre_scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight;')
run_time, max_run_time = 0, 1
while True:
    iteration_start = time.time()
    # Scroll webpage, the 100 allows for a more 'aggressive' scroll
    driver.execute_script(
        'window.scrollTo(0, 100*document.body.scrollHeight);')

    post_scroll_height = driver.execute_script(
        'return document.body.scrollHeight;')

    scrolled = post_scroll_height != pre_scroll_height
    timed_out = run_time >= max_run_time

    if scrolled:
        run_time = 0
        pre_scroll_height = post_scroll_height
    elif not scrolled and not timed_out:
        run_time += time.time() - iteration_start
    elif not scrolled and timed_out:
        break

price_of_pieces_fiat = driver.find_elements(
    "xpath", "//div[@class='sc-fe5f9c83-0 mGAUR Price--fiat-amount']")

for price_of_piece in price_of_pieces_fiat:
    print(price_of_piece.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

These are the numbers I receive:

````
$556.73
$18,989.53
$2,226.92
$1,590.66
$6,362.64
$795.33
$318.13
$1,590.66
$1,590.66
$858.96
$3,817.58
$2,385.99
$6,680.77
$2,306.46
$12,104.92
$779.42
$4,167.53
$556.73
$556.73```

When I am expecting hundreds or thousands of these values.
````

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is it only collects 19 random points

`opensea.io` has two problems:

1. The rows displayed in the site don't have the same order than the rows in the HTML.
2. As you scroll down, the new rows are added to the HTML but the old rows are removed from the HTML.

Both problems are shown in the GIF below. In particular, you can see that the last `div[role=listitem]` in the HTML represents actually the first row displayed in the site. How is this possible? If you look carefully each row has a style attribute `top` which indicates where the row is displayed. The first displayed row has `top: 0px`. As you scroll down, new rows with higher and higher `top` attribute are added to the HTML.

[image]

This explains why you get only few prices and also why they are "random". In order to get all the prices you have to slowly scroll down and extract the prices from the rows currently in the HTML.

The following code does exactly this. It scrolls only 9 times but you can increase it

```
import re
prices = []
for i in range(9):
    for price in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'Price--fiat-amount')]"):
        prices.append(price.text)
    
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role=listitem]')
    # get the "top" style attribute value of each row
    top_px = [int(re.findall('\d+', re.findall( 'top:\s*\d+px' , row.get_attribute('style') )[0])[0]) for row in rows]
    # the bottom row is the one with the higher/max "top" value
    bottom_row = rows[ top_px.index(max(top_px)) ]
    # scroll to the bottom row
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', bottom_row)
    time.sleep(2)

print('We got', len(prices), 'prices:')
for price in prices:
    print(price)
```

Output

```
We got 147 prices:
$3,84
$4,74
$4,58
$4,26
$4,72
$1.307,52
$4,74
$3,16
$3,16
$3,16
$3,16
$4,74
$4,26
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$4,58
$4,26
$4,72
$3,84
$1.307,52
$4,74
$3,16
$3,16
$3,16
$3,16
$4,74
$4,26
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,90
$3,90
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$4,58
$4,26
$4,72
$4,74
$3,95
$3,95
$3,90
$3,32
$3,16
$3,79
$3,16
$4,74
$3,90
$3,90
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,95
$3,90
$3,16
$3,16
$157,91
$1.579,13
$3,13
$1.096,23
$1.247,51
$3,79
$3,32
$3,16
$4,74
$3,95
$3,90
$3,90
$3,95
$3,95
$3,16
$157,91
$3,47
$3,63
$931,69
$3,47
$3,63
$2.826,64
$1.579,13
$3,13
$3,16
$1.096,23
$1.247,51
$3,79
$3,32
$3,16
$4,74
$3,16
$157,91
$3,63
$3,16
$3,16
$3,16
$3,16
$787,99
$3,16
$931,69
$3,47
$3,63
$3,47
$2.826,64
$1.579,13
$3,13
$1.247,51
$3,63
$3,16
$2,68
$4,58
$3,95
$4,58
$4,58
$3,79
$3,16
$3,16
$3,16
$787,99
$3,16
$931,69
$3,47
$3,63
$2.826,64
$3,16
$2,68
$4,58
$3,63
$3,63
$3,63
$3,55
$3,63
$3,95
$3,95
$4,58
$4,58
$3,79
$3,16
$3,16
$787,99
$3,16
```